# Laravel 5.2 - Eloquent Many to Many Relationship

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, relationship

I have 2 models and 3 migrations, **Models are**

**1-**`Media`:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Media extends Model
{
  public function gallery(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Gallery', 'media_gallery');
    }
}
```

**2-**`Gallery`:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Gallery extends Model
{
  public function media(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Media', 'media_gallery');
    }
}
```

and **Migrations are**

**1-** for `media` table the schema is:

```
Schema::create('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

**2-** for `gallery` table the schema is:

```
Schema::create('galleries', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->timestamps();
   $table->string('path');
   $table->string('type');
});
```

**3-** a third joining table for `media_gallery` *many to many* relationship:

```
Schema::create('media_gallery', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->integer('media_id');
    $table->integer('gallery_id');
});
```

**Concept:** I have Dropzone installed and working so than I can upload items to the `Gallery` table, but what I want to do is that I make a `Media` item so that it holds one or more `Gallery` items, and a `gallery` item can be related to many `media` item

**What** I've tried:
I made a form that holds each gallery item with a check box holds the `id` of the item, this is how I handle it in my controller...

```
public function MediaPostUpload(Request $request){

        $media = new Media();
        $media->save();

        //fetching ids of checked boxes
        $galleryItems = $request['galleryItems'];
        $ids = array();
        if(!empty($galleryItems)){
            foreach($galleryItems as $itemId){
                $ids[] = $itemId;
            }
        }
        $media->gallery()->attach($ids);
}
```

**Error** shows up:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'galleries.media_gallery' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `galleries` where `galleries`.`media_gallery` = 1 and
>   `galleries`.`media_gallery` is not null)

Comment: You should use `belongsToMany` in Media model too.

Comment: not the inverse relation ? why is that? I'm new and if I got some declaration to understand it would be great

Comment: I don't know if it will solve your problem, but many to many doest have inverse relations, it is the same relation because the pivot will always have both keys

Comment: this solved my case I tried it.. may you type it as answer to give you points on it ?

Comment: Sure! It is done! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use belongsToMany association in your Media Model too:

```
class Media extends Model
{
  public function gallery(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Gallery', 'media_gallery');
    }
}
```

Many to many doesn't have inverse relations, it is the same relation because the pivot will always have both keys.